# GatsbyJS and Netlfiy string vs number in markdown

Tags: graphql, markdown, gatsby, netlify

I'm having trouble with a datetime field in gatsby.

Originally I just used the string widget in netlify cms but markdown couldn't seem to decide what is a number and what's a string:

[image]

Which means gatsby sees conflicting field types:

```
warn There are conflicting field types in your data.
MarkdownRemark.frontmatter.startTime:
 - type: number
   value: 1080
 - type: string
   value: '07:00'
MarkdownRemark.frontmatter.endTime:
 - type: number
   value: 1140
 - type: string
   value: '08:00'
```

So I explicitly define them with the `createTypes` action as per gatsby's suggestion:

```
schema.buildObjectType({
            name: 'Frontmatter',
            fields: {
                startTime: {
                    type: 'Date',
                    // resolve(parent){
                    //     console.log(parent.startTime);
                    // }, 
                    extensions: {
                        dateformat: {
                            formatString: "HH:mm",
                        },
                    },
                },
                endTime: {
                    type: 'Date',
                    extensions: {
                        dateformat: {
                            formatString: "HH:mm",
                        },
                    }
                },
            },
        }),
```

But that produces either `00:00` or `"Invalid date"`

I use the netlify timepicker to set the values:

```
- { label: "Start Time", name: startTime, widget: datetime, date_format: false, time_format: HH:mm, format: HH:mm}
      - { label: "End Time", name: endTime, widget: datetime, date_format: false, time_format: HH:mm, format: HH:mm}
```

Is there a way I can force markdown to see strings instead of numbers? Or to see a datetime? Or get netlify cms to always save it as a string?

Answer (score 0):

I have also had this problem and have discovered that the version of the YAML parser used by Gatsby (currently `js-yaml@3.14.1`) is parsing strings as base60 where possible. Which I believe is not compliant with the YAML 1.2 spec.

This issue has [since been fixed in version 4](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml/commit/19185199e0cc6357869afde7194bb2239ef67917#diff-06572a96a58dc510037d5efa622f9bec8519bc1beab13c9f251e97e657a9d4ed) but unfortunately the libraries that Gatsby uses still depend on version 3. `gatsby-transformer-remark@4.3.0 -> gray-matter@4.0.3 -> js-yaml@3.14.1`

An attempt to force upgrade using `npm-force-resolutions` did not work but
fortunately [gray-matter allow engines to be swapped using the options](https://stackblitz.com/edit/gray-matter-problem). Also gatsby-transformer-remark allows the gray-matter options to be configured within gatsby-config.js.

So I have managed to workaround the issue by installing js-yaml@4.1.0 and overriding the engine like so:

package.json

```
{
...
  "dependencies": {
+    "js-yaml": "4.1.0",
```

gatsby-config.js

```
+ const yaml = require('js-yaml');
...
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-transformer-remark",
      options: {
+        engines: {
+          yaml: {
+            parse: yaml.load.bind(yaml),
+            stringify: yaml.dump.bind(yaml)
+          }
        },
```